# Accidentally moved my files with a sudo command to a non-existent directory. Now I can't find my files

Tags: macos, bash, monterey, file, sudo

On my mac, I tried moving all my .pdf files from my `/Downloads` directory to my documents directory but I made a typo. I used the following command:

```
sudo find Downloads -name "*.pdf" -exec mv {} /Users/Downloads \;
```

The mistake I made was that `/Users/Downloads` isn't an existing directory and now I can't find my files. I was supposed to move the files to `/Users/[System name]/Documents`. I think that I made a mistake because the path that it should be moved to should be `/Users/[name of the system/Downloads \;`

I've tried searching for the lost files to no avail. Is there any way to recover my .pdfs? Any method for recovering the files would help me greatly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you move a file to a folder that doesn't exist, the file is renamed to become the [intended] folder name. Check the file on your machine entitled `/Users/Downloads`, it may be -one- of the PDF files you moved. The rest may be gone, and might only be able to be restored if you have a backup.

Comment: The files are considered deleted and won't affect my storage in any way, right?

Comment: Yes, the files are deleted (with the exception of one of them, perhaps), and are not using storage space.

Comment: This is why you should always use `mv -i` or `mv -n` for any sort of bulk/automated move. (I know, too late... but just keep this in mind for next time.)

Comment: What happened is that the system executed the mv command once for each file found. So first time, it renamed the file, the other times it overwrote the previous renamed file. The result is that you get the last file from find command and it can be any of it : order of find is not the same as ls .